# Code to update records worked with SQL Server but does not work with Access (OleDb)

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, sql-update, oledb

My code was working with ASP.NET and SQL Server, but after changing the database connection from SQL Server to an Access file (via OleDb) nothing is happening.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim myCONN As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\Baza.mdb")

Dim query As String = "UPDATE Baza SET NAZIV = @newNAZIV, PUN_NAZIV = @newPUN_NAZIV  WHERE SIFRE=@SIFRE"
myCONN.Open()
Using instruction As New OleDbCommand(query, myCONN)

    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SIFRE", TextBox1.Text)
    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newNAZIV", TextBox2.Text)
    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPUN_NAZIV", TextBox3.Text)

    instruction.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
myCONN.Close()
```

Can anyone explain why the code would work with SQL Server not with Access? The UPDATE statement is very straightforward so it is not a matter of differences in the SQL dialects (and I'm not getting a syntax error anyway).

Comment: I've edited my question even though I didn't understood why it's off-topic. I've changed connection from SQL to OLEDB and now it doesn't work and I come here asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the `.Parameters.AddWithValue()` statements to match the order in which the parameter placeholders appear in the CommandText. OleDb **ignores** parameter names and only pays attention to the *order* in which the parameters are added (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).